# Is 학습할 a participle in the following extract?

Tags: translation, verb-endings, tense

각 단원에서, 학습할 한글 자모의 획순과 발음, 음절 구성을 제시합니다.

● 각 단원에서

In each chapter,

● 학습할 한글 자모의 획순과

the Hanguel character order **that will be** learnt, and

```
      * (한글 자모의 획순) = Korean character order
      * (학습할) = THAT WILL be learnt.
```

● 발음, 음절 구성을 제시합니다.

Pronunciation and syllable structure is presented.

Questions:

1. Is it all translated correctly?
2. Is 학습할 a participle and part of a relative clause?

Comment: Hi - if part 2 will be closely related to part 1, feel free to put them together in a single question.

Comment: Ok. By the way am I allowed to ask people to check my translations on here?

Comment: https://korean.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic and https://korean.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/151/should-we-change-our-off-topic-rules-to-allow-small-translations hopefully explain our thoughts...

Comment: I hope someone answers it

Comment: I hope to take a look at unanswered questions this weekend~

Comment: please also maybe check this one - I will pay you bro ^_^
 https://korean.stackexchange.com/questions/3308/i-would-appreciate-if-you-could-help-me-translate-this-from-my-beginner-level-te

Answer (score 1):

> Is 학습할 a participle ...?

I think so, yes. It's a form of a verb that is used in this sentence to modify a noun, and plays a role similar to an adjective - which agrees with most definitions of 'participle'.

> ...and part of a relative clause?

Yes. But here, perhaps it isn't obvious what 'noun' the relative clause is referring to. Is it "한글 자모의 획순", the whole phrase "한글 자모의 획순과 발음, 음절 구성", or just "한글 자모"?

Although I couldn't tell you a scientific reason why, I think the natural reading is for it just to modify "한글 자모".  So for a full translation of

> 각 단원에서, 학습할 한글 자모의 획순과 발음, 음절 구성을 제시합니다.

My attempt would be:

**In each unit, we present the stroke order, pronunciation, and syllable structure of the Hangul characters that will be studied.**