# How can I break down this sentence to translate it 'literally' one piece at a time?

Tags: grammar, translation

*I would appreciate if you could help me to translate this and also if you could refer me to any important grammatical structures in here that I should learn.*

I understand the meaning - but I want to try translate it "directly" into English - one small piece at a time - so it's easy for me to match the original text to the translation.

[image]

**My second attempt:**

모든 단어의 끝소리는
•   The ending sound of all words, 
모음으로 시작되는조사나 어미(와)
•    Postposition particles (조사) or the end of a word(어미), THAT begins with a vowel (i.e. 으세요 in the example), AND

결합하는 경우 받침이
•   scenario in which it’s combined with Patchim

뒤 음절 
•   In next syllable (i.e. after the Patchim)

첫소리로 옮겨 발음됩니다.
•   (Patchim) moves (옮겨) to the “first(첫소리) (postion)” when pronounced.

*Please note I am trying to translate it "directly" into English so it's easy to match the Korean content to the English translation. And then after translating it directly I want to try to re-arrange it of course.*

Comment: As I said - I know the general meaning - but I can't really piece it all together when I translate it sentence for sentence... This is my last attempt at translating something at such a high level...

Comment: I've changed the title a bit to make it more obvious to other site users what (I think) you were asking for - I hope I understood you OK!

Comment: Yep 100%. It looks good.

Answer (score 3):

I find this quite hard to break down too - it's a reasonably long sentence, which makes it hard to hold it all in your head, and it's hard to spot the points where you can break it up. However, breaking the sentence down at conjunctions is still our best tactic.

First of all, the '는' topic particle provides an easy place to split :

> 모든 단어의 끝소리는

*("we're talking about") all words' ending sounds...*

Ok, let's read on a bit...

> 모음으로 시작되는 조사나 어미

*particles or word endings that start with a vowel*

That's not too bad, but we're starting to look for the next place to break up the sentence. The best place here is probably 는 경우, a construction meaning 'in this situation'; 'when'. So let's split there, and **pretend** that the sentence just ends with '결합**한다**'. That gives us:

> 모든 단어의 끝소리는 모음으로 시작되는 조사나 어미 와 결합한다

*All words' ending sounds are joined to particles or word endings that start with a vowel.*

Bearing in mind that 는 경우 means 'when', let's look at the rest of the real sentence:

> 받침이 뒤 음절 첫소리로 옮겨 발음됩니다.

*the final consonant is pronounced as if moved to the first sound of the next syllable*

Putting it all together:

> 모든 단어의 끝소리는 모음으로 시작되는 조사나 어미 와 결합하는 경우 받침이 뒤 음절 첫소리로 옮겨 발음됩니다.

we get a literal translation something like:

*When all words' ending sounds are joined to particles or word endings  that start with a vowel, the final consonant is pronounced as if moved to the first sound of the next syllable.*

Or, with the English made a bit more natural:

***When a word's final consonant is joined to a particle or word ending that starts with a vowel, it is pronounced as if moved to the first sound of the next syllable***.

Answer (score 0):

syllable : 음절

> When a (last) consonant (placed under a vowel) of a syllable meets
>   subsequent syllable, in postposition particles (조사) or the end of
>   a word (어미), that starts with a vowel, then the consonant is
>   joined to the vowel. Accordingly, the first syllable lose sound of
>   the consonant and the second obtains it as a first sound.

When a (last) consonant (placed under a vowel) of a syllable meets subsequent syllable,

=> 음절의 받침이 다음 음절을 만날때,

in postposition particles (조사) or the end of a word (어미),

=> 조사 또는 어미에 있는,

that starts with a vowel, => 모음으로 시작하는

then the consonant is joined to the vowel. => 받침은 모음과 결합한다.

Accordingly, the first syllable lose sound of the consonant and the second obtains it as a first sound.

=> 즉, 첫 음절은 받침 소리가 없고, 두번째 음절에서 첫소리가 된다.